# Play Framework 2.5.4 cannot connect to Oracle database

Tags: oracle, jdbc, playframework

the application.conf file :

```
default.driver = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
default.url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_name:port/sid"
default.jndiName=""
default.username = username
default.password = "password"
```

However, after doing this there seems to still be a small configuration issue as I am getting an error. I have searched extensively and found a number of similar issues online, but due to version differences none of them resolved the problem.  Any help is greatly appreciated. This is the full error message I get when trying to open my app :

```
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [
default]]
        at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
        at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:806)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:
48)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:
42)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
        at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72)
        at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62)
        at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:58)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(Provider
InternalFactory.java:81)
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Driver not found:
[oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver}]]
        at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
        at play.api.PlayConfig.reportError(Configuration.scala:996)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase$$anonfun$driver$1.apply(Databases.scala:1
14)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase$$anonfun$driver$1.apply(Databases.scala:1
08)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.driver$lzycompute(Databases.scala:108)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.driver(Databases.scala:107)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:122
)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
Caused by: play.api.PlayException: Cannot load Driver[Driver [oracle.jdbc.Oracle
Driver] cannot be instantiated.]
        at play.utils.Reflect$.createInstance(Reflect.scala:142)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase$$anonfun$driver$1.apply(Databases.scala:1
10)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase$$anonfun$driver$1.apply(Databases.scala:1
08)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.driver$lzycompute(Databases.scala:108)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.driver(Databases.scala:107)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:122
)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:138)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at play.utils.Reflect$.getClass(Reflect.scala:147)
        at play.utils.Reflect$.createInstance(Reflect.scala:136)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase$$anonfun$driver$1.apply(Databases.scala:1
10)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase$$anonfun$driver$1.apply(Databases.scala:1
08)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play does not automatically include all database drivers as dependency of your project. If I'm correct, only the H2 in-memory database is included.

You will need to add the Oracle JDBC driver as dependency of your project.
For example by adding to your dependencies in build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.oracle" % "ojdbc7" % "12.1.0.2"
```

However for this to work, you must add the Oracle Maven Repository to your list of repositories. See [Oracle Maven Repository](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/application/maven/index.html) (you need to register, but since you have an Oracle DB, you probably are).

When you cannot add the Oracle Repository to your project or the internal repository of your company, you can download the jar and put it in the /lib directory of your project. It is then an unmanaged dependency.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have a few questions about this though. How do I know which ojdbc.jar file I should use. I saw in another thread to move that jar into my lib folder inside the project. I tried with ojdbc6 and 7, but i see you have ojdbc14 here. Also, what does the 10.2.0.2.0 mean?

Comment: You are correct in that ojdb7 is actually the latest version. I will update the answer.

Comment: I tried that, but received this message :

[info] Resolving com.oracle#ojdbc7;12.1.0.2 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.oracle#ojdbc7;12.1.0.2

[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.oracle#ojdbc
7;12.1.0.2: not found

Comment: The issue was that I had my jar file in the activator directory as opposed to my project directory. Moving the jar to the project directory solved the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: more Oracle shit, this is why I hate oracle,solution will no more working, Directory browsing is not allowed on the Oracle Maven Repository!, the solution now is manually download driver and place it to classpath.